# change ssh port but i did not add port to firewall

Tags: ssh, sftp

I change ssh port to xxx but I forgot to add xxx to ufw rules firewall and I can not connect to my server now.
Is there any way to fix this issue. Also, I use sftp instant of ftp

Comment: did you mean `Also, I use sftp instant of ftp`?

Comment: i believe you will need to access the console to access the means to correct this problem.

Comment: yes you are right... the server support help me with vnc connection

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issues 
i use VNC connection also some way than can be useful
use PHP script to execute Linux command line 
use ftp with root access if you are not use sftp
contact to your server's support

Comment: such a PHP script would be unsafe because it would let someone take over your server.

Comment: it can be protected by username and password